# Failed to write to file error - ADODB.stream

Tags: windows, vbscript, windows-10, adodb

I want to download files from the internet with a .vbs file. I got the code here: [Is it possible to download using the Windows command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/59465/is-it-possible-to-download-using-the-windows-command-line)

It uses ADODB.stream to extract the file to my C drive. I ran it on Windows XP SP3    and it worked fine. Then when I tried to run it on Windows 10 I got a "could not write to file" error. I also tried it in CMD with "cscript.exe download.vbs" and the same thing happened. What is the difference between Windows XP and Windows 10 that makes this error? Can it be fixed?

Here is the exact code:

```
strFileURL = "http://www.it1.net/images/it1_logo2.jpg"
strHDLocation = "c:\logo.jpg"
Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
objXMLHTTP.open "GET", strFileURL, false
objXMLHTTP.send()
If objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
Set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objADOStream.Open
objADOStream.Type = 1 
objADOStream.Write objXMLHTTP.ResponseBody
objADOStream.Position = 0    
Set objFSO = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If objFSO.Fileexists(strHDLocation) Then objFSO.DeleteFile strHDLocation
Set objFSO = Nothing
objADOStream.SaveToFile strHDLocation
objADOStream.Close
Set objADOStream = Nothing
End if
Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing
```

Comment: Starting with Windows Vista, you cannot write to the root of the C: drive unless you are running with elevated permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this might appear to be a programming issue it is in fact related directly to the Operating System. The change you've encountered between Windows XP and Windows 10 is known as [User Account Control](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) *(first introduced with Windows Vista)*.

As stated in [How do I get permissions to save in a folder that Windows 7 denies me from?](https://superuser.com/a/33377/95106)

> *This is due to UAC (User Access/Account Control) On Windows Vista / 7, and trying to write to a protected folder.*

In Windows 10 the root of the system drive *(usually the drive where the OS is installed)* is classed as a Protected Folder.

Accessing Protected Folders requires elevated privileges which when running VBScript through the Windows Scripting Host can be done by starting the command prompt in Administrator Mode *(available from the program context menu)* and calling the `wscript.exe` or `csscript.exe` with the required script path.